# python If else condition for json value

Tags: python, json

I have a scenario to develop but its not working and throws index error whenever I refer the JSON value since it does not exist and I need to implement if else condition for that value. Not sure how to deal with this scenario.
I receive a JSON file through another script, it sometimes comes with runorder:1 and sometime comes with both runorder:1 and runorder:2. I need to implement a condition if runorder:2 is present in file then only perform certain commands and if there is just runorder:1 present then perform certain commands.

Please find the sample payload i receive,

```
{
                "name": "Build",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "name1",
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "EnvironmentVariables": "[{\"name\":\"ACTION\",\"value\":\"DDB\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\"}]",
                            "ProjectName": "name2"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "name3",
                        "runOrder": 2,
                        "configuration": {
                            "EnvironmentVariables": "[{\"name\":\"ACTION\",\"value\":\"GLUE\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\"}]",
                            "ProjectName": "name4"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I need to check if runorder 2 is present in the file then only perform if statement but it directly gives me index error without doing the action
Also, if I try to take index or lenght then it throws error as no legth for integer value

```
import json
import sys
import os
#os.chdir(sys.argv[2])
#print sys.argv[2]
# get the absolute path to json file
Path_To_Param = 'params.json' #  assuming same directory
Path_To_Pipeline = sys.argv[1]+'.json'
# read existing json to memory. you do this to preserve whatever existing data. 
with open(Path_To_Param,'r') as paramfile:
                  json_param = json.load(paramfile)
with open(Path_To_Pipeline,'r') as pipelinefile:
                  json_content = json.load(pipelinefile)
                  print json_content['pipeline']['stages'][0]['actions'][0]['runOrder'])
if json_content['pipeline']['stages'][1]['actions'][1]['runOrder'] > '1'
json_content['pipeline']['stages'][1]['actions'][0]['configuration']['EnvironmentVariables'] = json_param['EnvironmentVariables']
json_content['pipeline']['stages'][1]['actions'][1]['configuration']['EnvironmentVariables'] = json_param['EnvironmentVariables1']
json_content['pipeline']['stages'][0]['actions'][0]['configuration']['BranchName'] = json_param['BranchName']
else
json_content['pipeline']['stages'][1]['actions'][0]['configuration']['EnvironmentVariables'] = json_param['EnvironmentVariables']
json_content['pipeline']['stages'][0]['actions'][0]['configuration']['BranchName'] = json_param['BranchName']
with open(Path_To_Pipeline, "w") as pipelinefile:
                  json.dump(json.dumps(json_content),pipelinefile, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: when loaded `json` data will be presented as `dict` in python. one can use `get` method of `dict` to retrieve a value. `get` can return a value if the wanted key does not exist. see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp

Comment: Hi @MSH, thanks for the response. The issue I am coming across here is while putting an if condition since I am not really understanding as runorder:2 comes few time and other times as its not present it directly gives me index error as it does not find the value in json file. So, how can I deal with this scenario if you can suggest something. I would be really grateful.

Comment: Hi @Lbits. Do you realize, `actions` is a `list`? So you'll have `runOrder`s as much as the length of the `actions`.

Comment: Hello MSH, thanks for the response. Yes, i understand that actions is a list and runOrder will give the length of the actions. I had a query here, for example, if I use Get method and allocate some value to runorder key for everytime what will happen if the runorder comes during other runs. Will it overwrite the value for me to compare or it will still give me the value which is allocated by me.